# Using Active Directory user info with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory

I have a SQL backed project on a corporate domain and the users are all members of the company's Active Directory.

I really don't want to create a seperate SQL user DB and cache names, email, etc..

I would rather store the Active Directory objectSid or objectGuid (which is best?) for the user in question in my SQL tables rows when a record needs to be tied to a user rather than make a cache of Active Directory users.

What is the best approach here? I've written a few CLRs AND with a CLR sproc, I can generate a LDAP query to get the specific active directory records from ObjectSids I'm using as pointers to records in Active Directory from my MsSQL database.

Is this really the best approach here? This is painful and while adequate for my needs, I'm thinking there must be a less cumbersome approach.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method and in my opinion the best, is to create a small service that will take your AD information and populate/update a table in SQL server. We have a service that runs once every hour or so and it keeps the table up to date. We use the ADGuid to identify users, that way any changes to name, adlogin, email address etc do not affect the database. You can then use referential integrity to ensure users exist in AD.

Our apps use ADFS to log users in so we always have the guid that identifies the user and can grab any extra info required from the table.

You don't want to poll AD everytime a user performs an action, the database is so much more effecient and you can always cache the user info in the app on a sliding/absolute scale if needs be.